# How to reset nested Stack Navigation navigators react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

**getting an issue with reset the stack navigator with send data in params**

Issue in sending params in nested stack

```
navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ name:'ChatBot', params: { boxData: boxData } }],
        params: { isBox: false }

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved this issue with sending data in params**

100% worked data is sending from in nested stack with params

```
navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [
          {
            name: "ChatBot",
            state: {
              routes: [
                {
                  name: "ChatBot",
                  params: {         
                    data:deepLinkData
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```